# "Unable to initialize OpenGL renderer library" при установке Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

При запуске *Genymotion* получаю такую ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

Драйвера все последние - специально проверяла.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Написанное в окошке уже проделали?

Comment: Да все последнее

Comment: проделанное вами похоже на то, что предлагают [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23561229/4827341)?

Comment: да, спасибо, я это видела..даже скачала OpenGL Extensions Viewer, чтобы убедиться соответствию драйверов.. у меня поддерживает версию 4.2 (надо 2.0)..еще в поиске решения)